# Login in Blazor WASM not working in Chrome after update

Tags: google-chrome, authentication, iis, blazor, blazor-webassembly

from today, I can't login (after Chrome updated both PC and mobile) in my Blazor WASM hosted ASP.NET Core project, published on IIS on the server. I have no error
If I use Edge or Firefox the login will works fine.
I also reset Chrome settings but I didn't solve.
On other PCs the login works fine also with Chrome.
Any suggestion, please?

Comment: Is there error in the network log? Like no-referrer-when-downgrade ?

Comment: Did you see any exception or error response status  in developer tool? Could you give a screenshot for that?

Comment: warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
      Failed to determine the https port for redirect.

Comment: info: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator[0]
      Showing error: prompt=none was requested but user is not authenticated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved using HTTPS instead of HTTP binding site.